# Extract Module File Schema from SharePoint

Tags: tools

What I want to do is get the xml for the module like this I do not have to write it myself.

I would like to know what is the easiest way to extract the schema of a existing page.

For the moment I am using the Save site as Template and then open the wsp with Visual Studio but it's a long operation.

Somebody has a tool which does that?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into elements files in publishinglayouts folder (feature) under FEATURES directory of sharepoint root, you will see examples. In general you will find many examples if you explore the FEATURES directory.